# Where exactly does readFIle or writeFile perform operation asynchronously in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I was learning Node.js and came across asynchrony and how does it work behind the scenes. Also, as we know there are such functions  as `fs.readFile and fs.writeFile` functions that work asynchronously. So, the question I wanted to ask is where exactly `fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` methods asynchronously reads and writes the entire contents of the file. Are they passed to thread pool or Node API to not block main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we start up a node program node automatically creates one thread and then executes all of our code inside of that one single thread. Node.js is not a programming language it is an environment that we can run javascript and javascript is the single threaded.

Javascript doesn't know how to read a file from disk but C++ does. So when someone uses javascript code and node.J S to read a file from disk, it just defers all of that to the C++ function that can actually read the file from disk and get the results back.

V8 will see the javacript implementation of readFile and will translate it to the c++ version and libuv creates the thread pool to run the c++ functions here. by default libuv creates 4 thread pools, and thread pool allows us to run more tasks concurrently.

imagine you have 4 different functions to read files, and your cpu has 4 cores, each thread from thread pool will be assigned to one core, so all of the reading file functions will be completed at the same time.